# jupyter-lab: How to stop a long-running function with an ipywidget button?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

In jupyter-lab I have a long running function `long_runner()` doing some heavy numeric computation. I would like to be able to stop this function by clicking on an ipywidget button. Interrupting the kernel is not an option since other parts of the GUI should continue working.

Here is a code example with a button which sets a stop flag. This stop flag is used in `long_runner` to break out of the loop. When `long_runner` is active, the Button seems to be reactive to clicks, but the associated function `set_stop_flag` is only executed after `long_runner` has finished normally and thus no intermediate stop is possible.

I looked at some examples with asyncio but could not find something fitting this use-case with a heavy-compute function.

How could the desired behavior be acchieved?

```py
from ipywidgets import Button

stop_flag = 0
def set_stop_flag(b):
    global stop_flag
    print("stop flag activated")
    stop_flag = 1
    
b=Button(description="stop")
b.on_click(set_stop_flag)
display(b)

def long_runner():
    x=0
    print("starting ...")
    for i in range(100000000):
        if stop_flag==1:
            print("stop=",stop_flag)
            break
        x += i*i
    print("stopping",i)
    return(x,i)

print(long_runner())
```

Here is the program output when the stop-button is clicked during the execution of `long-runner`:

[image]

Comment: I've got some links to examples available [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-make-start-and-stop-buttons/8331/4?u=fomightez). I think the timer one is closest. You may want to look more around the links and discussion on that thread as well for refining your code. For understanding the use of multiprocessing, you might like this [simple example](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/running-a-cell-in-a-background-thread/12267/3?u=fomightez) that works in JupyterLab.

Comment: And I have an example of using multiprocessing to monitor a long-running 'external' process and then terminate it when it seems it should be done [here](https://github.com/fomightez/AnimatePymolWithJmol/blob/e710cab10bddddd63880baf2d48a77119bad39d1/AnimatePyMOL2Jmol.ipy#L114) when the output file seems to be done increasing in size. It is part of this effort that you can run the demo of in Jupyter by pressing the badge that says `launch making animations from PyMOL using Jmol` [here](https://github.com/fomightez/AnimatePymolWithJmol).

Comment: A [related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71205664/8508004).

Answer (score 2):

following the first comment (thanks!), specifically this [link][1] I was able to modify the example such that one can now interrupt the `long_runner` with a button. The key is to start `key_runner` in a thread. Below is the program followed by the output when clicking the button after a few iterations. The `sleep(1.0)` is only made to limit the output freqency and is non-essential.

```py
import threading
import numpy as np
from ipywidgets import Button
import time

stop_flag = 0
def set_stop_flag(b):
    global stop_flag
    print("stop flag activated")
    stop_flag = 1
    
b=Button(description="stop")
b.on_click(set_stop_flag)
display(b)

def long_runner():
    x=0
    print("starting ...")
    for i in range(100000000):
        time.sleep(1.0)
        print(f"x={x} i={i} stop_flag={stop_flag}")
        if stop_flag==1:
            print("stopped at i=",i)
            break
        x += i*i
    print("stopping")
    return(x,i)

thread = threading.Thread(target=long_runner)
thread.start()
```

Output:

(imagine button here)

````
starting ...
x=0 i=0 stop_flag=0
x=0 i=1 stop_flag=0
x=1 i=2 stop_flag=0
x=5 i=3 stop_flag=0
x=14 i=4 stop_flag=0
x=30 i=5 stop_flag=0
stop flag activated
x=55 i=6 stop_flag=1
stopped at i= 6
stopping```


  [1]: https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-make-start-and-stop-buttons/8331/4?u=fomightez
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bchu.png
````