# how to abort a job using ipywidgets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am creating a button that runs a job when clicked using ipywidgets all inside of a Jupyter Notebook. This job can take some long amount of time, so I would like to also give the user the ability to stop the job.

I've created a minimally reproducible example that runs for only 10 seconds. All of the following is run from a Jupyter Notebook cell:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
from time import sleep

button = widgets.Button(description='run job')
output = widgets.Output()


def abort(event):
    with output:
        print('abort!')

    
def run_job(event):
    with output:
        print('running job')
        button.description='abort'
        button.on_click(run_job, remove=True)
        button.on_click(abort)
        sleep(10)
        print('job complete!')

button.on_click(run_job)
display(button, output)
```

If the user clicks 'run job', then waits 2 seconds, then clicks 'abort'. The behavior is:

```
running job
job complete!
abort!
```

Which implies the 'abort' event fires after the job is already complete. I would like the print sequence to be:

```
running job
abort!
job complete!
```

If the abort can fire immediately when clicked, then I have a way to actually stop the job inside of my class objects.

How can I get the abort event to run immediately when clicked from a Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Meant to reply earlier. Just a quick note since I'm heading out. What you describe needs to involve multiple processes/threads or possibly asyncio, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/threading-with-matplotlib-and-ipywidgets/14674/2?u=fomightez) for some inspiration. I'll probably delete this soon if I think of how to address your case later.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I will look into this. And also please post a solution if you have time I am happy to give credit where credit is due.

Comment: Awesome that you got it! I should have also pointed at [this thorough answer with multiple approaches demonstrated with code here under 'Kill a loop with Button Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71223447/8508004). I'm still adding it as the additional pointers may help someone else who ends up here.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at that as well. The more approaches the better, I am having some success in my notebook but looking for a better way to accomplish this in another area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After being pointed in the right direction by Wayne in the comment section, `asyncio` seems to provide the desired capability within Jupyter Notebooks and ipywidgets. In the following discourse thread bollwyvl posts a solution for how to use asyncio to accomplish a similar pattern
https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/threading-with-matplotlib-and-ipywidgets/14674/2?u=fomightez

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
from time import sleep
import asyncio

button = widgets.Button(description='run job')
tasks = dict()

def abort(event):
    print('abort!')
    task = tasks.pop("run_job", None)
    if task:
        task.cancel()

async def run_job():
    print('running job')
    button.description='abort'
    button.on_click(run_job, remove=True)
    button.on_click(abort)
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print('job complete!')

def start_job(event):
    button.description='abort'
    button.on_click(start_job, remove=True)
    button.on_click(abort)
    tasks['run_job'] = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(run_job())
    print('started job')

button.on_click(start_job)
display(button)
```

When 'start' button is clicked, then 'abort' button. The following output is produced:

```
started job
running job
abort!
```